# Using Two GroupDescriptions on a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, grouping, collectionviewsource

I have a listbox which contains a collection of Photos. The photos are currently Grouped by the Date they were taken. E.g.:

> ---03/09/14
>
> 03/09/14 photo 1,
>
> 03/09/14 photo 2,
>
> 03/09/14 photo 3,
>
> --02/09/14
>
> 02/09/14 Photo 1
>
> 02/09/14 Photo 2

**Xaml:**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding FilteredPhotoFiles}">
   <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
       <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PhotoMetaData.DateTaken" Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeConverter}"/>
   </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

But now I would like to add a Favourited Group. I have a `List<Photos>` and `List<FavouritedPhotos>`
But is there any way that favorited photos can override the group collection. E.g.

> --Favourited
>
> 03/09/14 photo 2,
>
> 02/09/14 Photo 1
>
> ---03/09/14
>
> 03/09/14 photo 1,
>
> 03/09/14 photo 3,
>
> --02/09/14
>
> 02/09/14 Photo 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was possible using help from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx)

I edited the Xaml to read

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding FilteredPhotoFiles}">
   <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
       <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Favourited"/>
       <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="PhotoMetaData.DateTaken" Converter="{StaticResource DateTimeConverter}"/>
   </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

where favourited was a boolean property on my ViewModel